# Transfer Phone number between projects

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to transfer a phone number between 2 projects using this [Guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts), but am getting this error:

> The AccountSid you are transferring to is not related to the originating owner of the phone number.

```
 public string SwapPhoneAccount()
    {

        // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        const string accountSid = "Assssssssssssssssssssssss";
        const string authToken = "******************";

        // In the case you want to transfer numbers between subaccounts, you need to
        // know three things - the account SID of the phone number's current owner,
        // the account SID of the account you'd like to transfer the number to, and
        // the SID of the phone number you'd like to transfer
        const string currentOwnerSid = "Assssssssssssssssssssssss";
        const string newOwnerSid = "Awwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww";
        const string phoneNumberSid = "Arrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr";

        // Create an authenticated REST client
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        IncomingPhoneNumberResource.Update(phoneNumberSid,pathAccountSid:currentOwnerSid,
                                           accountSid: newOwnerSid);
        return "good";
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Joseph Krausz, please add your code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: Look my EDITED post

Comment: Are the account sids you're using in your code *subaccount* sids or Project sids.  You can transfer phone numbers between subaccounts in a single project, but you'll need to reach out to Twilio support to transfer between projects: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135327-Moving-Twilio-phone-numbers-to-another-Twilio-project